# How is tab completion for environment names configured in recent anaconda versions (2019.10 specifically)?

Tags: anaconda, environment, tab-completion

I have anaconda3 installed on 2 machines and both are 2019.10 version.  On one of the machines, if I type `conda activate <tab>` bash will produce a list of my environments.  I've never done anything specific on this machine to enable this - it just works.  On the other machine, my environment names were not produced.  I cannot tell where the difference might be captured - I've looked in ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, and /etc/profile.d and didn't find anything noteworthy between the two systems.

I've tried installing conda-bash-completion, and that actually made it worse.  Now, instead of not producing anything with the above command, it produces a list of basically all files/folders in my current directory, none of which are environments.  Further, I've removed conda-bash-completion and yet this new behavior persists.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `conda --version` info (from both machines) would be relevant to include.

Comment: sorry - the machine that "works" is 4.8.0 and the machine that doesn't is 4.8.2

Comment: @merv Rolling back conda to 4.8.0 did the trick.  It looks like 4.8.1 stopped relying on bash-completion and opted for conda-bash-completion, but that latter still looks like a work in progress.  Thanks!